# how to solve org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -4

Tags: java, hibernate

my query in the code is

```
 ArrayList lst = genericDao.query("select * from fdfiles where fileid = " + fileId);
```

At this line i get the exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -4
```

How do i over come the above exception.

my hibernate has properties

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

the log file shows

```
java.lang.Exception: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -4; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -4
at com.duncansolutions.databus.dao.GenericDao.query(GenericDao.java:135)
at com.duncansolutions.databus.service.mechanismmanagement.datakey.FileListByLocationDaoService.getFile(FileListByLocationDaoService.java:151)
at com.duncansolutions.databus.html.DatakeyFileDownloadController.getFilebyId(DatakeyFileDownloadController.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:174)
```

Comment: [1]Which driver are you using? [2]Can you provide complete stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

This **No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -4** exception seems when the hibernate is trying convert result list actual list, `hibernate` is not able to identify column `dataTypes`.

Try to use `HSQL` to fetch records like below.

Assumeing that your `fdfiles` is Mapped to `FdFiles` Entity

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT fd.propert1,fd.property2 FROM FdFiles fd WHERE fd.fileId = :fileId");
                query.setParameter("fileId", fileId);
                List<FdFiles> list = query.list();
```

Comment: but if i do like above,even the associated table values will also be retrieved ,which is expensive.i am using inheritence in fdfiles,so is there a way to retrieve only the required table data.

Comment: You can add selected properties in Select list. i have updated my post